# Java - Why won't these two classes communicate with eachother?

Tags: java, class, methods, communication

I'm trying to get Bil to get a name from Person by having the method Bagare() in Bil talking to bilagare() in Person. My intention is to have bilagare() get the name via avläsNamn() (also in Person). What am I doing wrong? I'm certain there are easier ways to do this but it's an assignment in Java-class where we have to use the classes and methods mentioned above. Following are the two classes Bil and Person

```
package Objektorientering_kap_4;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Bil{

Person ba;

public String regNum(){

    String registrering = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange registreringsnummer, utan mellanslag");

    char l1 = registrering.charAt(0);
    char l2 = registrering.charAt(1);
    char l3 = registrering.charAt(2);
    char n1 = registrering.charAt(3);
    char n2 = registrering.charAt(4);
    char n3 = registrering.charAt(5);

    String N = ""+n1+n2+n3;
    int NS = Integer.parseInt(N);

    if(registrering.length() == 6 && 000 <= NS && NS <= 999 ){

    String regnum = registrering;

    return(regnum);    

    }
    else{

        String error = "Error";
        return(error);

    }


}

public String bilmarke(){

    String marke = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange bilmärke");

    return(marke);

}

public String modell(){

    String bilmodell = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange bilmodell");

    return(bilmodell);

}

public String Bagare(){

    String namn = ba.bilagare();

    return(namn);

}

}
```

and

```
package Objektorientering_kap_4;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Person{

private String namn, adress;
private Person makeMaka;

public Person(String n){

    namn = "Sven";

}

public String avläsNamn(){

    return namn;

}

public void sättAdress(String adr){

    adress = adr;

}

public String avläsAdress(){

    return adress;

}

public void bröllop(Person p){

    makeMaka = p;
    p.makeMaka = this;

}

public void skilsmässa(){

    makeMaka.makeMaka = null;
    makeMaka = null;

}

public Person giftMed(){

    return makeMaka;

}

public String bilagare(){

    String agare = avläsNamn();

    return(agare);

}

}
```

Comment: you never initizalized the Person Object?

Comment: you should try to follow the naming conventions with your `getter` and `setter` methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Person ba` is a *reference* to a person object, not an actual instance.  If you want a person object you need to write

```
Person ba = new Person("name");
```

otherwise you have written what is effectively.

```
Person ba = null;
```

so when you use `ba` you get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Tried this already, it returns an error telling me to create a constructor in Person

Comment: @ZolidG Your constructor has to have a name. (Even though it is ignored, you still need to produce something) I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize your `ba` variable, so it's null and you can't call any methods of `Person` through that null reference. Perhaps you should pass to the constructor of `Bil` a `Person` object.

Answer (score 0):

Create instance of `Person` object using `new` operator `Person ba = new Person()`.